# Descargar archivo con React y Express

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, express

Buen dia
Quiero descargar un archivo con React desde una API. Para descargar el archivo estoy usando "js-file-download" pero de alguna manera al abrir el archivo se encuentra vació, no se que estoy haciendo mal

Este es mi codigo con node

```
        const idProyecto = req.body.idProyecto;
        const idActividad = req.body.idActividad;
        const nombreArchivo = req.body.nombreArchivo;

        const appDir = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../');
        const ruta = `${appDir}/archivos/${idProyecto}/${idActividad}/${nombreArchivo}`;
        if(fs.existsSync(ruta)){
            const stat = fs.statSync(ruta);
            res.writeHead(200,{
                "Content-Type": mime.lookup(ruta) as string,
                'Content-Length' : stat.size
            })
            const read = fs.createReadStream(ruta);
            read.pipe(res)
        }
```

Este es mi codigo en react

```
import download from 'js-file-download';

const respuesta = await descargarArchivosFromServer(busqueda);
download(respuesta, nombreArchivo);
```

Esto es lo que me trae respuesta.data

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué estas tratando de descargar? Un pdf, una imagen? Me huele a que debes realizar el stream primero antes de descargarlo

Comment: Pareciese que estás teniendo un problema con el formato del archivo, esto parece como si abrieras un pdf con block de notas jaja

Comment: Quiero poder descargar cualquier tipo de archivo.